# Delete temp files from \Temp folder using Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

For my own purpose, I'm creating a windows service that once a day will delete my temp files (from the \Temp folder). Of course, in time when I don't use the computer.
I already created the service and installed it using InstallUtil.exe. Now I'm testing it.
I found that if some of the temp files is used by another process, the deleting process cannot continue.
So my question in a few words - is there a way to exclude these used files or some function that kills the processes that use these files?

If someone wants to see my code, here is my project -> [DeleteService](https://slavenakolevaa.visualstudio.com/DeleteTempFilesService/DeleteTempFilesService%20Team/_git/DeleteTempFilesService)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. It really needs to be in the question, not as an external link.

Comment: The short answer is - add a `try catch` around every delete. In your `catch` do nothing (i.e. swallow the exception). This will effectively ignore files that it can't delete.

Comment: I thought that it will be good to show the entire project but I will know for the future :). About the `try catch` - I will try it.